# Sending Email Based on Cell Value within a Loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, outlook

I have a sample sheet
[image]

I have a module that runs through the list in a loop within another loop, checking for duplicate names and then grouping the names together to send an email with an attachment based on Column D (Division).

Sample 4 would get one email with 3 attachments.

I have been asked to build in the ability to exclude people based on a value (I chose yes or no, column C) before running the module.

Reason being that if the list is long (over 1000 names) to set it before generating the emails.  I would build in a trigger to set that value, but it is apparently an arbitrary decision made by the senders in a dept.

I have tried to build an `IF` statement into the loop as shown below but it is as if the `If` statement  is coming out as not being true (I stepped through).
Which means all the `With Outmail` objects will not work.

I was able to get it to work by using the if statement with a for/next setup on its own (no loops), but cannot get it to work with the loop, which is the more important piece.

Here is the main piece of code. The main loop and then the if statement to account for the yes or no values:

```vb
Do While r <= rng.Rows.Count
If rng.Cells(r, 3).Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And LCase(rng.Cells(r, 3)) = "yes" Then     
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
End If
```

And here is the full sub:

```vb
Sub EmailDivisions()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim cell, lookrng As Range
    Dim strDir As String
    Dim strFilename As String
    Dim sigString As String
    Dim strBody As String
    Dim strName As Variant
    Dim strName1 As Variant
    Dim strDept As Variant
    Dim strName2 As String
    Dim strName3 As Variant    
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
    sigString = Environ("appdata") & _
                "\Microsoft\Signatures\Divisions.htm"
                              
    If Dir(sigString) <> "" Then
        signature = GetBoiler(sigString)
    Else
        signature = ""
    End If
        
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    r = 2
        
    Do While r <= rng.Rows.Count
        If rng.Cells(r, 3).Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And LCase(rng.Cells(r, 3)) = "yes" Then
         
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        End If
         
        Set strName = rng.Cells(r, 1)
        Set strDept = rng.Cells(r, 4)
        strName2 = Left(strName, InStr(strName & " ", " ") - 1)

        With OutMail
            strFilename = Dir("\\Divisons\1a*" & strDept & "*")
            .SentOnBehalfOfName = "divisionalsend@xyz.org"
            .To = rng.Cells(r, 2).Value
            .Subject = "Monthly Divisional Report for " & strDept
            .HTMLBody = "<Font Face=calibri>" & "Dear " & strName2 & ",<br><br>" & signature
            .Attachments.Add strDir & strFilename
                            
            'See if the next row is for the same sender.  If so, process that
            'row as well.  And then keep doing it until no more rows match
            Do While rng.Cells(r, 2).Value = rng.Cells(r + 1, 2)
                r = r + 1
                Set strDept = rng.Cells(r, 4)
                strfilename1 = Dir("\\Divisions\1a*" & strDept & "*")
                .Subject = "Monthly Divisional Report for Your Departments"
                .Attachments.Add strDir & strfilename1
            Loop
            .Display

        End With
        Set OutMail = Nothing
        r = r + 1
    Loop
    Set OutApp = Nothing
          
End Sub

Function GetBoiler(ByVal sFile As String) As String
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = FSO.GetFile(sFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    GetBoiler = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the edits braX, appreciated and understood for the future.

Comment: When you step through, and hover over `LCase(rng.Cells(r, 3))` what does it show you? My first guess is that `rng` isn't what you think it is. You could also add `debug.print LCase(rng.Cells(r, 3))` just before your if statement to print out the value to the immediate window. Which you can view by pressing `ctrl+g`.

Comment: @jcarroll, so I did try to see the intellisense but for some reason it actually does not show anything when on it or past it.  I thought that was weird too.  It shows nothing for that whole line.  When I add the debug.print, it shows the word yes.  That led me to see that I made a STUPID mistake and had it keyed to column 3 and 3 instead of 2 and 3!  So, that made it run finally but now when it hits the first 'No' I am back to the same error.  I am trying to change my logic statement to make it skip the ones with No and get back into the loop.  Working on it, but any ideas?  Thanks!!

Comment: You should put the `End If` after `Set OutMail = Nothing`.

Comment: More: you are using rng correctly. You just do not need it. `Cells(r, 1)` and `rng.Cells(r, 1)` are identical (in case `Usedrange` begins in A1). And I would put the number of rows to a var instead of using `rng.Rows.Count` in every loop. And I would revise `Set`s in front of `str*` vars. You declare them as variant but you use them as strings.

Comment: Thanks all, I made some of the changes in the comments but still  cannot get this to run correctly.  I have it still erroring out when it hits the line to set the .sentonbehalfofname, so the first object in the With block.  Which tells me that it is not setting the Outmail, right?  How do I get it to do what I want, skipping the 'NO' items and return back to the loop?

Comment: Also, it is now working through the yes items fine, just when it hits the first no item, it stumbles.  I think I need to get it to run an elseif where it jumps back to the loop, but I do not know how to do that....I know how to jump back to a 'next' item, but not a loop.

Comment: Okay guys, I think I figured it out, will post the full sub shortly!  Thanks for the input!  Figured out that I could goto a loop via ContinueLoop.

Comment: Is `division`? attachment name?

Comment: @0m3r, yes it is, but I figured it out and posted the code that worked below, hoping it will help others in the future.  For the attachment, you can see it here:   `strFilename = Dir("\\Divisons\1a*" & strDept & "*")` where strDept is `Set strDept = Cells(r, 4)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, here is the final sub:

```
Sub EmailDivisions()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim cell, lookrng As Range
Dim strDir As String
Dim strFilename As String
Dim sigString As String
Dim strBody As String
Dim strName As Variant
Dim strName1 As Variant
Dim strDept As Variant
Dim strName2 As String
Dim strName3 As Variant


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

sigString = Environ("appdata") & _
        "\Microsoft\Signatures\Divisions.htm"

If Dir(sigString) <> "" Then
 signature = GetBoiler(sigString)
 Else
 signature = ""
End If

Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

r = 2


Do While r <= rng.Rows.Count
Debug.Print LCase(rng.Cells(r, 2))
If Cells(r, 2).Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And LCase(Cells(r, 3)) = "yes" Then

       Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
       ElseIf Cells(r, 2).Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And LCase(Cells(r, 3)) = "no" Then GoTo ContinueLoop

       End If

Set strName = Cells(r, 1)
Set strDept = Cells(r, 4)
strName2 = Left(strName, InStr(strName & " ", " ") - 1)

With OutMail
    strFilename = Dir("\\Divisons\1a*" & strDept & "*")
    .SentOnBehalfOfName = "divisionalsend@xyz.org"
    .To = Cells(r, 2).Value
    .Subject = "Monthly Divisional Report for " & strDept
    .HTMLBody = "<Font Face=calibri>" & "Dear " & strName2 & ",<br><br>" & signature
    .Attachments.Add strDir & strFilename
.display

    'See if the next row is for the same sender.  If so, process that
    'row as well.  And then keep doing it until no more rows match
    Do While rng.Cells(r, 2).Value = rng.Cells(r + 1, 2)
        r = r + 1
        Set strDept = Cells(r, 4)
        strfilename1 = Dir("\\Divisions\1a*" & strDept & "*")
        .Subject = "Monthly Divisional Report for Your Departments"
        .Attachments.Add strDir & strfilename1
    .Display
ContinueLoop:
        Loop

End With
Set OutMail = Nothing
r = r + 1
Loop
Set OutApp = Nothing




End Sub



Function GetBoiler(ByVal sFile As String) As String
Dim FSO As Object
Dim ts As Object
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = FSO.GetFile(sFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
GetBoiler = ts.ReadAll
ts.Close
End Function
```